# Cross platform mobile developement using UIWebView and Webview

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, uiwebview, webview

I am just wondering is it worth to do a cross platform mobile app development using UIWebView (iphone) and Webview(Android)? We need to port multiple web applications as mobile apps for iphone and Android. One of the strategy is to use the UIWebView to render content from server and this content from server is same for Android and iPhone.

Have a you developed using this concept? Is there any limitations you found in it? Such as issues with redirect of web-pages, cookies, java-script library performance etc

So far I see only two issues:

1. Non availability specific UI design features native to device such as may be rounded corner buttons not available etc
2. Infrastructure code for handling cookies, sending and receiving information back and forth from server to device.

any advice?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross platform frameworks are talking similar approach and also adding wrapper libraries to abstract away platform specific functionlity. Check out PhoneGap, Appcelerator and others.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Pyxis, which is a cross platform mobile app development software.

Comment: Note that Pyxis is a MEAP (mobile application enterprise  platform). You don't really code your app per se, more "configure" it. The app needs to communicate to a server running IIS and SQL server as well, that you have to be running.